Preparing Sylius Project - Deleting Sample Data
I need to present a web project to my college teachers in one month. The project is an online shop that I created using Sylius, following some online instructions. The website is fully functional, but it contains sample data that I want to delete. How can I safely remove the sample data without compromising the rest of the project? I'm concerned about breaking something, so I haven't attempted anything yet. Thanks in advance for your help.

Maybe this link to an issue on the GitHub will help you.

If you have already loaded dummy data:
bin/console sylius:install:database

Say yes to the question:
se sylius_dev exists and it contains some tables.
Warning! This action will erase your database.
Do you want to drop all of them? (y/N) y

Say No to the second question:
Loading sample data for environment dev from suite default.
Warning! This action will erase your database.
Continue? (y/N) n

Then:
bin/console sylius:install:setup

Answer the questions and that's it !
